# Find the cumulative distribution function of sum of two independent random variables

Tags: probability

> Given a a random vector $(X,Y)$ with joint density $f_{XY}(x,y)=c$ over trapezoid $(0,0),(0,1),(2,1),(3,0)$ I need to find the cumulative distribution function of $Z=X+Y$.

Support for $Z$ is $[0,3]$.

For $0\leq z\leq 1$:

$$F_z(z)=\int_{0}^{z}\left(\int_{0}^{z-x}c\ dy\right)dx$$

For $1\leq z\leq 3$:

$$F_z(z)=\int_{z-1}^{z}\left(\int_{z-x}^{1}c\ dy\right)dx$$

Are the integral bounds correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is correct; the second is not.  The reason is simple:  for your stated order of integration, the interval $z-1 \le x \le z$ will necessarily omit ordered pairs for which $x < 1$ when $z > 1$.

Instead, you would write for $1 < z \le 3$  $$F_Z(z) = \int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=0}^{z-y} c \, dx \, dy.$$

Now, you don't even need to do any integration:  you can calculate the areas directly through geometric considerations.  Your result should be $$F_Z(z) = \begin{cases} 0, & \phantom{0 < .} z \le 0 \\ z^2/5, & 0 < z \le 1 \\ (2z-1)/5, & 1 < z \le 3 \\ 1, & 3 < z. \end{cases}$$